# Use ADODB Recordset to INSERT Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, excel, adodb, vba

I am converting some Excel-VBA code that uploaded a DAO recordset to an Access database.  My new code uses ADODB objects and needs to push the data to Oracle 12c.

I reviewed some articles, and found a handy equivalency chart here:  [From-DAO-to-ADO](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/1490571/From-DAO-to-ADO.htm).  Using this information I created the following code.

This first bit just loads up the source recordset. No problems here, but published if it's relevant:

```
Dim CN As New ADODB.Connection, RS As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim SRC_CN As New ADODB.Connection, SRC_RS As New ADODB.Recordset, SRC_CMD As New ADODB.Command
strSQL = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Src_WB_nm & _
        ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO';"
SRC_CN.Open strSQL
Set SRC_CMD.ActiveConnection = SRC_CN
SRC_CMD.CommandType = adCmdText
SRC_RS.Close
Set SRC_RS = Nothing
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & TableNm & "]"
SRC_CMD.CommandText = strSQL
With SRC_RS
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .Open SRC_CMD
End With
```

In this segment, I open the destination connection and attempt to open the destination recordset.  Thismethodology (AddNew, RS...value = RS.value, RS.Update...) worked when I was in DAO.  I expect it may need to be modified somewhat, but its the RS.Open command that I can't get past now.

```
CN.Open CSTRG
strSQL = "DELETE FROM DFSTOOL.C_QUERYLIST"
Set RS = CN.Execute(strSQL)
Set RS = Nothing
RS.Open "DFSTOOL.C_QUERYLIST", CN, adCmdTable
Do Until SRC_RS.EOF
    RS.AddNew
    RS.Fields(0).Value = SRC_RS.Fields(0).Value
    RS.Update
    SRC_RS.MoveNext
Loop
RS.Close
SRC_RS.Close
Set RS = Nothing
Set SRC_RS = Nothing
```

The error thrown is: [image]

I appreciate any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So happily this was a simple syntax issue.  Perhaps I should delete the post, but I'll leave it for now in case it helps anyone else.  The equivalency table I referenced noted that the "adCmdTable" is an option in ADO, whereas the equivalent "dbOpenTable" was a type in DAO.  Thus, I was required to skip a few fields so that it was in the right location.  Other fine-tuning followed and the final iteration works as expected:

```
RS.Open "DFSTOOL.C_QUERYLIST", CN, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
Do Until SRC_RS.EOF
    RS.AddNew
    RS.Fields(1).Value = SRC_RS.Fields(0).Value
    RS.Update
    SRC_RS.MoveNext
Loop
```

Thanks for your patience community!